# Unable to bootstrap a node with chef: Cannot load configuration

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a Chef workstation and a Chef server running. `pmchef.org` is my chef node with a sudo user `pmchef`. When I run the knife bootstrap command I get this error message (from the node being bootstrapped):

**FATAL: Cannot load configuration from /etc/chef/first-boot.json**

This is the paste from the bash terminal (on the workstation; which is my laptop)

```
pm:~/chef-repo/chef-repo$ sudo knife bootstrap -x pmchef pmchef.org
Password:
Connecting to pmchef.org
pmchef@pmchef.org's password:
pmchef.org bash: line 35: /etc/chef/validation.pem: Permission denied
pmchef.org chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/chef/validation.pem’: No such file or directory
pmchef.org bash: line 69: /etc/chef/client.rb: Permission denied
pmchef.org bash: line 77: /etc/chef/first-boot.json: Permission denied
pmchef.org Starting first Chef Client run...
pmchef.org [2015-02-26T10:01:54+00:00] FATAL: Cannot load configuration from /etc/chef/first-boot.json
```

Comment: Okay I figured out what solves the problem, I just ran the knife bootstrap with a sudo. `knife bootstrap -x pmchef pmchef.org --sudo` and it all worked. So it was a problem with the permissions.

Comment: Yes you definitely have to bootstrap a node as a privileged user.